# Flutter - Calculating Total Price from DATABASE

Tags: json, flutter, dart, fetch, price

I have some problem, I want to calculate total price when I fetch the datas from my database. Actually I can calculate total price but I cannot control because it returns infinitely, the codes below here:

my json codes:

```
[
{"parca_fiyat": "900"},
{"parca_fiyat": "100"},
{"parca_fiyat": "500"},
]
```

and my flutter:

```
FutureBuilder<List<dynamic>>(
future: getData(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    return Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Container(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 6),
                              child: Text(
                                'Toplam:' +
                                    () {
                                

                                      for (var i = 0;
                                          i < snapshot.data.length;
                                          i++) {
                                        number += double.parse(
                                            _parcaFiyat(snapshot.data[i]));
                                      }
                                     return number.toString();
                                    }() +
                                    ' ₺ + KDV',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                                  fontSize: 16,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        );
```